# A consequence of the open mapping theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

We let $f$ be a bounded and surjective linear map from the Banach space $X$ onto the Banach space $Y$ and put
$$
r_0=\inf\{r: f(B^X(0,r)\supset B^Y(0,1)\}.
$$
Using the open mapping theorem, I have shown that $0<r_0<\infty$ (in fact $||f||\geq 1/r_0$) and that 
$$
f(B^X(0,r_0)\supset B^Y(0,1).
$$
 But I'm still wondering if
$$
f(\overline{B^X(0,r_0)}\supset \overline{B^Y(0,1)}
$$
holds or not?

Comment: Try $f:c_0 \to \mathbb R$, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \mapsto \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n/2^n$.

Comment: @Jochen Great example, thanks so much!! I'm not sure if I should write it up as an answer below or delete this question or simply leave it as it is?

Comment: You are right, I should have written this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example $f:c_0\to \mathbb R$, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N} \mapsto \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n/2^n$ shows that the statement for the *closed* balls does not hold in general.

Comment: $\|f\|=1$ in this example. $1$ is in the closure of the image of the closed unit ball but not in the image.

Comment: Yeah, nice example.  $r_0=1$. In this case both the open unit ball and the closed unit ball map to the same open interval: $f(B(0,1)) = f(\overline{B(0,1)}) = (-1,1)$.